# How this regex matches in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add trailing slash to a url. I have my own logic to do so but found another one on stackoverflow ([here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124582/wordpress-in-sub-directory-wp-admin-problem)). Now the regex in this line

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
```

apparently matches the RewriteRule for the url http://www.example.com/wp-admin.

What I first did was:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-admin$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/+$
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:proto}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

So my question is how `/wp-admin$` is similar to `^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is purpose of lookbehind here `(?<=/)wp-admin$` and not just `/wp-admin$` ?

Comment: @anubhava
To match the previous '/' so I would ensure "wp-admin" after a '/'.
Both RewriteRule works fine. As `^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$` should not find match in http://example.com/wp-admin (at-least in pcre) how does it work in htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because leading slash is matched when you use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` but current directory (relative to `DocumentRoot`) is stripped when you use a pattern in `RewriteRule` in .htaccess file, which is a per directory directive.

Hence a leading slash is not matched in `RewriteRule` but is matched in `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @OP: Did I answer your query?